# Маршрут отрезками по точкам на Яндекс картах

Tags: api, yandex-maps-api

Помогите, пожалуйста, на яндекс карте отобразить маршрут отрезками (не учитывая дороги, границы). Т.е. есть массив точек и нужно их соединить отрезками.

Comment: Я вбил заголовок в поиск  и мне выдало решение. Минус за отсутствие попыток самостоятельно решить проблему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В API Карт есть инструмент для рисования ломанных линий. [Пример в песочнице](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polyline?from=SO)

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  // Создаем карту.
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.72, 37.44],
    zoom: 10
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  });


  // Создаем ломаную с помощью вспомогательного класса Polyline.
  var myPolyline = new ymaps.Polyline([
    // Указываем координаты вершин ломаной.
    [55.80, 37.50],
    [55.80, 37.40],
    [55.70, 37.50],
    [55.70, 37.40]
  ], {
    // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
    // Содержимое балуна.
    balloonContent: "Ломаная линия"
  }, {
    // Задаем опции геообъекта.
    // Отключаем кнопку закрытия балуна.
    balloonCloseButton: false,
    // Цвет линии.
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    // Ширина линии.
    strokeWidth: 4,
    // Коэффициент прозрачности.
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });

  // Добавляем линию на карту.
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolyline);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ломаная</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="polyline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А как сделать,  чтобы точки добавлять динамически в полигон или создавать полигон со своим массивом данных?

Comment: аналогично примеру, просто задавая точки программно)