# Как автоматизировать прокладку маршрута на карте яндекса

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, svg-animation

У меня есть приложение, которое реализует движение персонажей анимации вдоль заранее проложенного маршрута на карте города. Маршруты, точнее `path` сделаны вручную в векторном редакторе. [Вся техника создания маршрутов показана здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/870990/28748).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код, реализующий данную технику и анимацию:

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1"   viewBox="0 0 800 540"  >
  <defs>
   <path id="walk"
   d="m343 268 34-10 50-9-33-86 22-14 7-21 8-3 13 18 34-25 47 65 22-19"  />
  <g id="Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1,-1)">
    <path   fill="none">
         <animate
          attributeName="d"
          begin="0.1s"
          dur="0.3s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path> 
   </g>
  </defs>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPdWW.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <path id="train" stroke-dasharray="312" stroke-dashoffset="312" stroke-width="2" d="M443 534 426 477 415 435 397 391 375 347 350 304 334 277 317 251" style="fill:none;stroke:violet;"/>
  
    <text
      font-size="28"
      font-family="Times New Roman"
      fill="#517DA6" >
<textPath id="result"
xlink:href="#train">
<tspan dx="0" > &#128642; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">  &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15">   &#128643; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15">   &#128643; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15" >   &#128642; </tspan>
 <animate id="anTrain"
   begin="0s;an5.end"
   dur="12s"
   repeatCount="1"
   attributeName="startOffset"
   values="-60%;45%;45%;-60%"
   fill="freeze"/> 
</textPath>
</text>  
  
  <path id="walk"
   stroke-dasharray="409"
   stroke-dashoffset="409"
   stroke-width="3"
   d="m343 268 34-10 50-9-33-86 22-14 7-21 8-3 13 18 34-25 47 65 22-19"
   style="fill:none;stroke:#B34EE9">
  <animate id="anPathWalk"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   begin="anTrain.end-7.5s"
   dur="2s"
   values="409;0"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  

 
 <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:blue; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an2"
       begin="anPathWalk.end"
       dur="16s"
       repeatCount="1"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>  

     </use> 

   <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:crimson;" > 
     <animateMotion id="an3"
       begin="anPathWalk.end+0.5s"
       dur="17s" repeatCount="1"  >
             <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
      </animateMotion>  
  </use> 
    <use xlink:href="#Man"
       transform="translate(0,0)
       scale(1)"
       style="stroke:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an4"
       begin="anPathWalk.end+1s"
       dur="13s"
       repeatCount="1"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
      </animateMotion>  
    </use>    
    
    <use xlink:href="#Man"
       transform="translate(0,0)
       scale(0.8)"
       style="stroke:red;
       fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an5"
       begin="anPathWalk.end+1.5s"
       dur="11s"
       repeatCount="1"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>  
    </use>  
     <use xlink:href="#Man"
        transform="translate(0,0)
        scale(0.8)"
        style="stroke:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an5"
      begin="anPathWalk.end+1.8s"
      dur="9.5s" repeatCount="1"  >
         <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>  
    </use> 
  
</svg>
<audio src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Time_Machine.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"></audio> 
</div>
```

Возможно ли максимально автоматизировать прокладку маршрута из одной точки карты в другую с помощью создания ломанных отрезков `path` щёлкая мышкой по контрольным точкам карты, - у разветвления улиц, при изменении направления движения.

**Другими словами, - работа программы должна повторять работу в векторном редакторе, когда мы наносим узловые точки, которые автоматически соединяются отрезками линий, а на выходе мы получаем готовую формулу патча.**

[Есть топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935210/28748), в котором прокладка маршрутов реализована, но она требует указания координат вершин ломанных линий вручную.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первый раз работаю с Яндекс картами, был неприятно удивлен, что они поддерживают только целочисленное значение zoom, это осложняет синхронизацию карты с **svg** картинкой, в которой **zoom** может быть дробный.

Решение сделано при помощи d3.js, сперва необходимо при помощи мыши спозиционировать карту, затем нажать кнопку [image: add route] и появится **svg** оверлей, по которому можно кликать, прокладывая маршрут. В этом режиме drag правой кнопкой мыши таскает карту, клики левой добавляют точки в маршрут, даблклики по точкам удаляют их. Для того, чтобы получить SVG результат в виде SVG кода, нажмите на кнопку [image: get code]

---

Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS: принимаю предложения по анимации маршрута и другие предложения.

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<style>
body, #map, #overlay, svg, #bg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bg {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    pointer-events: all;  
}
button, textarea {
    pointer-events: all;
}
textarea {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
#ui {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
}
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2.2;
    stroke: red;
}
circle {
    pointer-events: all;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .2;
    cursor: move;
}
.selected {
    fill: #ff7f0e;
    stroke: #ff7f0e;
}
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}
.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
}
button {
    display: inline;
}
</style>

<div id="map"></div>
<div id="overlay" class='hidden'>
    <svg></svg>
</div>
<div id="ui">
    <div id="bg" class='hidden'>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class='fa fa-2x fa-code'></button>
        <button class='fa fa-2x fa-route'></button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

let lat = 60;
let lon = 30.3;
let zoom = 15;
let yMaps;

let points = [];
let transform = {};
let dragged = null;
let selected = points[points.length-1];

let line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveLinear);
let svg = d3.select("svg");
let canvas = svg.append('g');

let path = canvas.append("path")
    .datum(points);

svg.on("mousedown", mousedown)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)

d3.select(window)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup)
    .on("resize", adjustSize);

d3.select('.fa-route').on('click', showOverlay);
d3.select('.fa-code').on('click', showCode);

window.oncontextmenu = () => false;
ymaps.ready(startmap);
svg.call(createZoom());
adjustSize();
redraw();

function showCode() {
    toggleElement('#bg');
    let div = d3.select(document.createElement('div'))
        .html(svg.node().outerHTML)
    div.select('svg')
        .attr('zoom', yMaps.getZoom())
        .attr('lat', yMaps.getCenter()[0])
        .attr('lon', yMaps.getCenter()[1]);
    div.selectAll('circle').remove();
    d3.select('#bg textarea').html(div.node().innerHTML);
}

function showOverlay() {
    lat = yMaps.getCenter()[0];
    lon = yMaps.getCenter()[1];
    zoom = yMaps.getZoom();
    d3.select(this).classed('hidden', true);
    toggleElement('#overlay', false);
}

function toggleElement(selector, isVisible) {
    return d3.select(selector)
        .node()
        .classList
        .toggle('hidden', isVisible)
}

function applyTransform() {
    transform = d3.event.transform;
    canvas.attr("transform", transform);
    onTransform(transform);
}

function createZoom() {
    return d3.zoom()
        .filter(() => d3.event.button === 2)
        .scaleExtent([1, 1])
        .on("zoom", applyTransform);
}

function adjustSize() {
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    let h = window.innerHeight;
    svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h)
        .attr("viewBox", `${-w/2} ${-h/2} ${w} ${h}`);
}

function redraw() {

    canvas.select("path").attr("d", line);

    var circle = canvas.selectAll("circle.knob")
        .data(points, d => d);

    circle.exit().remove();

    let newNodes = circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .classed('knob', true)
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .on("mousedown", d => {
            selected = dragged = d;
            redraw();
        })
        .on("dblclick", deletePoint)
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attr("r", 6.5);

    circle.merge(newNodes)
        .classed("selected", d => d === selected)
        .attr("cx", d => d[0])
        .attr("cy", d => d[1]);

    if (d3.event) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

function mousedown() {
    if (d3.event.button !== 0)
        return;
    points.push(selected = dragged = 
                d3.mouse(canvas.node()));
    redraw();
}

function mousemove() {
    if (!dragged)
        return;
    let m = d3.mouse(canvas.node());
    dragged[0] = m[0];
    dragged[1] = m[1];
    redraw();
}

function mouseup() {
    if (!dragged)
        return;
    mousemove();
    dragged = null;
}

function deletePoint(d) {
    if (!selected)
        return;
    let i = points.indexOf(selected);
    points.splice(i, 1);
    selected = points.length ? 
        points[i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0] : null;
    redraw();
}

function startmap() {
    yMaps = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [lat, lon],
        zoom: 15,
        controls: []
    });
}

function onTransform(transform) {
    var merc = Math.cos(yMaps.getCenter()[0]*Math.PI/180);
    var z = zoom;// + Math.log2(transform.k);
    var s = Math.pow(2, z-1) * 256 / 180 / merc;
    yMaps.setCenter([
        lat + transform.y / s,
        lon - transform.x / s / merc,
    ]);
  //  yMaps.setZoom(z+1);
}

</script>
```

P.S. Карты могут быть и не яндекс

Comment: это отлично...хорошая реализация ...:) плюсик от меня

Comment: @Stranger in the Q впечатляет! Но нет вывода формулы патча, или я не понял, как это делается (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TTзадумка несколько иная, это веб приложение будет уметь создавать и открывать url, парсить его и показывать анимацию, дело в том что просто пути недостаточно, нужна геопривязка еще, по сути это path + широта + долгота + зум

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  Отлично, но это уже совсем другая история для более крутого приложения. В вопросе четко сказано, - нужен вывод формулы патча, который можно будет скопировать и использовать в анимации, например маршрутов движения до офиса. Совсем не обязательно делать это на интерактивной карте, можно как у меня в [ответе по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/870990/28748) прокладывать маршрут по скриншоту карты. Но патч обязательно нужен.  Просто прокладывать маршруты это стандартная функция яндекс карт.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вопросов нет, сделаю textarea

Comment: @Stranger in the Q я добавил ответ с подробной раскладкой, чтобы показать, что получается, если напрямую добавить патч в файл svg.  Если есть возможность, может быть поменять некоторые параметры в выводе формулы патч, как у меня в ответе в разделе - **Выводы**

Comment: Если кому-то это интересно - можно было бы сразу генерировать на выходе svg в который встроен кусок карты как фон

Answer (score 4):

Информации, скриншотов, сниппетов достаточно много, поэтому решил оформить отдельным ответом, так как этот объем не поместится в комментариях.

Хочу остановиться на некоторых аспектах применения замечательного решения @Stranger in the Q

Как я попытался применить данное решение:

- Выбираю на карте нужный фрагмент и делаю скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Добавляю узловые точки вдоль выбранного маршрута и вывожу код этого маршрута

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Копирую код в отдельный файл, в котором добавлен скриншот карты с помощью команды `<image>`

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1400" height="858" viewBox="-700 -429 1400 858" zoom="14" lat="60.02023833197165" lon="30.424723377333542">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKUKV.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
<path stroke="red" fill="none" d="M-669,34L-434,-160L-218,-47L-202,-50L-199,-40L-194,-28L-147,-7L1,67L99,116L96,75L93,-5L88,-89L86,-158L86,-297L-47,-352L-161,-130L-63,-71L-9,-173"></path>
</svg>  
</div>
```

- Произошёл сдвиг карты вправо и вниз из-за отрицательных значений
  `viewBox="-700 -429 1400 858"`
- Обнуляю    `viewBox="0 0 1400 858"`

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1400" height="858" viewBox="0 0 1400 858" zoom="14" lat="60.02023833197165" lon="30.424723377333542">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKUKV.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
<path stroke="red" fill="none" d="M-669,34L-434,-160L-218,-47L-202,-50L-199,-40L-194,-28L-147,-7L1,67L99,116L96,75L93,-5L88,-89L86,-158L86,-297L-47,-352L-161,-130L-63,-71L-9,-173"></path>
</svg>  
</div>
```

- Карта встала на место, но ушел влево и вверх `Path` маршрута

Чтобы вернуть `Path` на место добавляю команду к `<path transform="translate(700 429)"`

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1400" height="858" viewBox="0 0 1400 858" zoom="14" lat="60.02023833197165" lon="30.424723377333542">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKUKV.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
<path  transform="translate(700 429)" d="M-669,34L-434,-160L-218,-47L-202,-50L-199,-40L-194,-28L-147,-7L1,67L99,116L96,75L93,-5L88,-89L86,-158L86,-297L-47,-352L-161,-130L-63,-71L-9,-173"  stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></path>
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Выводы:**

чтобы получить исходное положение маршрута надо в коде, который выводит программа сделать следующие изменения

1. Заменить отрицательные значения  `viewBox="-700 -429 1400 858"`
   на нулевые   `viewBox="0 0 1400 858"`
2. Добавить команду к `<path transform="translate(700 429)"`

### Пример анимации

по маршруту, полученному  из программы @Stranger in the Q

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1400" height="858" viewBox="0 0 1400 858" zoom="14" lat="60.02023833197165" lon="30.424723377333542">  
<defs>
<path   transform="translate(700 429)" d="M-669,34L-434,-160L-218,-47L-202,-50L-199,-40L-194,-28L-147,-7L1,67L99,116L96,75L93,-5L88,-89L86,-158L86,-297L-47,-352L-161,-130L-63,-71L-9,-173"  stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"> 
 </path>
  <g id="Man" transform="translate(700 429) scale(1.5,-1.5)">
    <path   fill="none">
         <animate
          attributeName="d"
          begin="0s"
          dur="0.25s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path> 
   </g>
  </defs>    
    
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKUKV.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
<path id="walk"  transform="translate(700 429)" d="M-669,34L-434,-160L-218,-47L-202,-50L-199,-40L-194,-28L-147,-7L1,67L99,116L96,75L93,-5L88,-89L86,-158L86,-297L-47,-352L-161,-130L-63,-71L-9,-173"  stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none">
</path>

<use xlink:href="#Man"  style="stroke:blue; fill:none;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an1"
       begin="0s"
       dur="20s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>  
</use>   
    <use xlink:href="#Man"  style="stroke:purple; fill:none;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an2"
       begin="an1.begin+2s"
       dur="19s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>  
    </use> 
<use xlink:href="#Man"  style="stroke:green; fill:none;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an3"
       begin="an2.begin+1s"
       dur="18s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>  
    </use>  

</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: отрицательный viewbox очень удобен, намного удобнее стандартного. т.к. в полярных координатах намного легче считать относительно центра (0,0), я всегда делаю именно так, потом за эту точку (центр), осуществляется гео привязка, если делать привязку за один из углов сложнее синхронизировать с картой, т.к. она тоже характеризуется именно центром

Comment: может быть стоит сделать на выходе кнопку которая генерит картинку вместе с Image внутри, это да

Comment: @Stranger in the Q я же не настаиваю, ты и так сделал очень много. Я просто написал - "Если есть возможность" , чтобы и другие люди, не запутались, когда будут использовать твою программу.

Comment: так это, возможность есть, я просто умышленно делал 0.0 центром, и хотел привести доводы в пользу этого =)