# Линии и точки на картинке при помощи JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

Задача - кликнуть на картинке в точку (А), затем кликнуть курсором в любое место на картинке (B), между двумя этими точками должна появиться линия, линий может мыть множество, но если из конечной точки кликнуть на точку (А), то должно произойти замыкание, фигура с координатами (подобное можно увидеть в Яндекс Картах - Линии). Также, желательно, чтобы эти точки можно было двигать в случае неверного размещения. Есть ли готовые библиотеки которые могут мне помочь в реализации?

[image: Пример подобного скрипта]

Comment: Попробуйте погуглить: "как сделать paint на js", думаю, что Вам это очень поможет)

Comment: Paint гуглил, это совсем не то.

Comment: С чего Вы это взяли? Там так же рисуются линии, так же их можно двигать, просто придется чуть-чуть кастомизировать, Вы попробуйте, а если не получится - задавайте вопрос с приложенным кодом что не получилось, задачи тут за Вас никто решать не будет, по крайней мере бесплатно.

Comment: В моём сообщении не было запроса на решение моей задачи. Просто я не так часто работаю с JS, поэтому и спросил готовые библиотеки, может кто - то сталкивался. Смотрю в сторону Raphael и d3.js. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот поделка на d3.js: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let points = [];
let transform = {};
let dragged = null;
let selected = points[points.length-1];

let line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveLinear);
let svg = d3.select("svg");
let canvas = svg.append('g');
let path = canvas.append("path")
    .datum(points);

svg.on("mousedown", mousedown)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)

d3.select(window)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup)
    .on("resize", adjustSize);

window.oncontextmenu = () => false;
svg.call(createZoom());
adjustSize();
redraw();

function toggleElement(selector, isVisible) {
    return d3.select(selector)
        .node()
        .classList
        .toggle('hidden', isVisible)
}

function applyTransform() {
    transform = d3.event.transform;
    canvas.attr("transform", transform);
}

function createZoom() {
    return d3.zoom()
        .filter(() => d3.event.button === 2)
        .scaleExtent([1, 1])
        .on("zoom", applyTransform);
}

function adjustSize() {
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    let h = window.innerHeight;
    svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h)
        .attr("viewBox", `${-w/2} ${-h/2} ${w} ${h}`);
}

function redraw() {

    canvas.select("path").attr("d", line);

    var circle = canvas.selectAll("circle.knob")
        .data(points, d => d);

    circle.exit().remove();

    let newNodes = circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .classed('knob', true)
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .on("mousedown", d => {
            selected = dragged = d;
            redraw();
        })
        .on("dblclick", deletePoint)
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attr("r", 6.5);

    circle.merge(newNodes)
        .classed("selected", d => d === selected)
        .attr("cx", d => d[0])
        .attr("cy", d => d[1]);

    if (d3.event) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

function mousedown() {
    if (d3.event.button !== 0)
        return;
    points.push(selected = dragged = 
                d3.mouse(canvas.node()));
    redraw();
}

function mousemove() {
    if (!dragged)
        return;
    let m = d3.mouse(canvas.node());
    dragged[0] = m[0];
    dragged[1] = m[1];
    redraw();
}

function mouseup() {
    if (!dragged)
        return;
    mousemove();
    dragged = null;
}

function deletePoint(d) {
    if (!selected)
        return;
    let i = points.indexOf(selected);
    points.splice(i, 1);
    selected = points.length ? 
        points[i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0] : null;
    redraw();
}
```

```css
body,svg{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2.2;
    stroke: red;
}
circle {
    pointer-events: all;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
    fill: #ff7f0e;
    stroke: #ff7f0e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Была изготовлена для и извлечена из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957495/188366)

Comment: Благодарю, раньше я скептически относился к этой библиотеки из-за её веса. Но теперь вынужден её использовать. Уже смотрю все примеры которые потребуются мне для выполнения задачи.

Comment: @Dopster можно позависеть от модулей, будет сильно меньше весить, можно все тоже самое сделать и на голом js, будет слегка побольше кода, раза в 2

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Вау, это сильно. А может и есть что-то в frontende )))

Comment: @Denis640Kb спасибо, фронт фронту рознь :) сейчас всякие редакторы, компьютерные игры тоже своего рода фронтенд :)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Ну там же по больше части платформы уже ) Это не так интересно, а вот всё через алгоритмы и функции - это красота )

Comment: @Denis640Kb ну смотря какие задачи, вот я например попиливаю иногда примочки для насовской гис https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/web/ тут и графика и spatial алгоритмы, математика

Comment: @Denis640Kb потом всякие нетривиальные визуализации, программная верстка

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Ничего себе. Даже не знал, что такое есть. Надо попробовать пару примеров на питоне ) Спасибо за ссылку, очень полезно будет )

Comment: @Denis640Kb как то распинался тут про это в прошлом году https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717904/188366