# Как сделать компонент рисующий редактируемый многоугольник на React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Хотелось бы сделать это как [здесь](https://chi-lin.com/projects/react-annotation-tool). На данный момент имею [это](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hellman-h7jv8?file=/src/App.js) (покликайте по картинке). В моей реализации сейчас очень не хватает точек на вершинах. Также если расставить 4 точки в виде прямоугольника, то внутри него будет линия от которой хотелось бы избавиться. Хотелось бы получить от вас советы, решения или же ссылку на готовый пакет реализующий мои нужды. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Всё для ответа на вопрос должно быть в самом вопросе, а не по ссылкам

Comment: И каким образом относится к данному вопросу react?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/960820/188366