# Как перевести координаты с PaintBox X и Y в Longitude и Latitude (Openstreetmap)?

Tags: delphi, openstreetmap, координаты

Столкнулся с интересной задачей. 
У нас есть компонент TPaintBox на нем отображается условно какая-то часть карты взятая с Openstreetmap. Вопрос, как узнать широту и долготу, когда мы перемещаем курсор по данному компоненту, если нам известно следующие:

- Ширина и высота компонента TPaintBox: hBox = 400  | wBox = 800
- Из Openstreetmapизвестен текущий масштаб: 11
- Lon и Lat для верхней левой точки (0,0) :  Lon = 28.12  | Lat = 46.07
- Так же в пределах нашего TPaintBox перемещается наш курсор, то есть мы знаем положение X и Y
- тайлы с OpenStreet  всегда имеют длину и высоту: 256 pxl

Буду признателен за помощь с формулами, для ниже обозначенных функций, например как:

- function GetLonByX(APosX: Integer): Double;
- function GetLonByY(APosX: Integer): Double;

ЗЫ. Масштаб и начальные координаты Lon | Lat могут меняться...

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957495/188366 вот тут в сниппете я использую простенький пересчет, с учетом проекции меркатора(метод в самом конце), попробуйте так(там javascript, но не думаю что это важно)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Ваше решение верное!!! Мне оно помогло, если Вас не затруднит, выложите сюда часть этого кода, что бы я принял его как правильный ответ, а Вам засчитало балы :-) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот таким методом я пользуюсь для пересчета экранных координат в проекцию меркатора, правда это на `javascript`, `lat` и `lon` здесь центр карты, а `x` и `y` экранные координаты

```
var merc = Math.cos(yMaps.getCenter()[0]*Math.PI/180);
var scale = Math.pow(2, zoom - 1) * 256 / 180 / merc;
var position = [lat + y / scale, lon - x / scale / merc];
```

`zoom - 1` это в движке `яндекс` карт так, например в `mapbox` `-1` не нужен

`256` - размер тайла

PS: рабочий пример использования, есть вот в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/957428/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0/957495#957495)